# Open source web-based code and changeset viewer for git

Tags: git, open-source

Know of any good ones?  Looks like there were a few attempts at adding git support to [Warehouse](http://github.com/entp/warehouse) but it appears to be dead. I'm aware of Redmine but am looking for others.

I host git repos with gitosis on my local server and want a way to browse it on the web.

Comment: There are OSS git web interfaces in Perl, C, Python, Ruby, PHP; any preference?

Comment: I prefer Ruby, but it's not a huge issue..I would use any if the frontend is good enough. I'm currently looking at ginatra though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at "Web Interfaces" section of [Interfaces, frontends and tools](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/i/n/t/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools.html) page on Git Wiki.
 There you will find, among others, the following web interfaces:

- **[gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb)**, distributed with Git, written in Perl.  Used e.g. by [git.kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org) and [repo.or.cz](http://repo.or.cz/) (both use modified version of gitweb).
- **[cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/)**, written in C.  Used e.g. by [cgit.freedesktop.org](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/)
- [ViewGit](http://viewgit.sourceforge.net/), written in PHP.  You can see [demo here](http://code.fealdia.org/viewgit/) (*defunct?*).
- [ginatra](http://narkoz.github.io/ginatra) ([github](https://github.com/narkoz/ginatra)), written in Ruby, uses [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) web framework.
- [pitweb](http://pitweb.danfis.cz/), written in Python.

There are few other simple web interfaces (in Perl using Catalyst, in Python using Pyjamas, in PHP, in Ruby); see mentioned Git Wiki page for links and descriptions.  Most commonly used are I think ***gitweb*** and ***cgit***.

Beside simple web interfaces, there are also a few git hosting solutions, which include built-in web interface (like [GitHub](http://github.com) does):

- [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/), in Ruby ([code](http://gitorious.org/gitorious)).
- [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net/), in PHP, started as clone of Google Code ([code](http://projects.ceondo.com/p/indefero/)).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use [GitWeb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb), or Trac with git plugin.

Comment: GitWeb looks like the best out there currently.

Answer (score 2):

Besides GitWeb, [cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/) is a good choice, too.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

**[Gitalist](http://www.gitalist.com/)**, checkout an [example](http://example.gitalist.com/), or get the [source code](https://github.com/broquaint/Gitalist) at Github